# How to use progress dialog with AsyncTask and fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I want to use a `ProgressDialog` within a `Fragment` for an `AsyncTask`. With `Activity` the following code works perfectly, but with `Fragment` no.

```
public class ResultTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Report> {

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Context context;

    public ResultTask(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");

        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Report doInBackground(String... params) {
      //myLong operation

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Report report) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(report);
    }

}
```

How Can I fix in a very simple way ? The idea of the `ProgressBar`, is just to let understand the user, that a long operation is processed.

**UPDATE**

Here is the code of the Fragment, where I execute the AsyncTask:

```
ResultTask task = new ResultTask(getActivity());
Report report = task.execute("paramenters").get();
```

And this is the code of the Activity, where I select the Fragment:

```
private void changeActivity(Button button, final Fragment fragment) {
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: What is the problem in fragment?

Comment: in fragment for the context you should use getActivity() method

Comment: Post the code how you call the `AsyncTask` in Fragment.

Comment: I post the code of the Fragment

Comment: if you use getActivity(), make sure your fragment isAttached and getActivity != null

Comment: Thank you for your reply ! Where should I check if the fragment isAttached ?

Comment: Did you got any error or exception ? otherwise what is your exact issue ??

Comment: No error/exception, the problem is that the progress bar is not displayed

Comment: Dont use context of asynctask, try my code -> pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity);

Comment: I have moved the progressDialog in the Fragment with the use of execute().getResult(), but it isn't showed as before :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use .get() for an AsyncTask than it is going to WAIT there until the result not arriving, which case the UI thread to be blokced, while task is running.
USE .execute and use handlers to communicate with the task.
In this case, you don`t need a handler, because the onPre and onPost methods are related the UI, but the doInBackGround not :)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()

article:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html

Comment: What kind of handler should I use ?

Comment: In your case you don`t need handler, because you are just dismissing the dialog, so it is good to use the onPostExecute for this.

Comment: So to let display correctly the progress dialog, I need to create a method in the fragment, which will be called in the onPostExecute() method. isn't it ? In this case, the AsyncTask will not return directly the object Report. isn't it ?

Comment: No, just pass the dialog to asynctask constructor. On asynctask consturctor save it as instance reference. after it use this reference in onPreExecute and say: this.dialog.show();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80997/discussion-between-i-love-coding-and-karoly).

Comment: I have two more questions: why should I pass the getContext to the asyncTask ? Where should I dismiss the progress dialog ? Now the progress is showed once the operation has finished and I don't understand why...